# changes to the children of the grid dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement a search suggestion feature using the grid view of Xamarin forms. I was wondering if there is anyway to change the children of the grid dynamically according to the text get entered in the search box.

```
    grid.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                Text = x.Text,
                TextColor = Color.White,
                BackgroundColor = Color.Blue
            }, 0, x.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Grid , then you should specify row ands colums, otherwise all the texts will overlaps each other. Instead of Grid, you should use StackLayout.

```
hintSL  = new StackLayout(){
   HorizontalOptions= LayoutOptions.Fill,
   //Orientation = Vertical or Horizontal (however you want)
};

//if you want to add hintsSl into your grid
   Grid.SetRow(hintsl, 4);
   Grid.SetColumn(hintsl, 4);

searchText.Changed+=(s,e)=>{
   hintSL.Children.Clear();
   foreach(var hint in YourHintsList)
      hintsl.Children.Add(new Label(){Text=hint, and other properties});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do this:
The first is to use binding.  Bind the text field of the label to a bindable property that changes according to the user's entry.

The second is to make the label a member of whatever class holds the grid, rather than anonymous.  Then you can catch the event (eg OnEntryChanged) generated when the user enters the text and dynamically set the label in the code.